# Unexpected end of input on parameter.json()

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm learning about servers and **APIs**, I do not know too much about how data is received and sended through requests. So i got my server with **Node.js** using **Mongoose** and **Express.js**:

```
server.get('/api/items', async (req, res)=>{
    let results = await TvModel.find({model: 4013});
    res.json(results);
});
```

So if i send the get request via postman i get this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "60f62a33a1dbf8031088cd3b",
        "name": "Sony",
        "model": "4013",
        "size": 8,
        "idSerial": 1,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

So, trying to get the data via JavaScript using fetch api:

```
fetch(API_URL, {mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then((resolve) => {resolve.json()})
```

When executing this code, i get an error on the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

What is the SyntaxError i cannot see?

Comment: `{mode: 'no-cors'}` means you won't get any results - therefore, no JSON - did you add that header due to a CORS error perhaps thinking this will bypass CORS?

Comment: also, do `.then((resolve) => {return resolve.json()})` or `.then((resolve) => resolve.json())` - if you want access to the resulting response data - because `.then((resolve) => {resolve.json()})` basically throws away the response

Comment: you can use POSTMan to generate the code for you, it is really helpful when you are playing with headers and proxies.

Comment: share the complete error message for the same. If your are not able to share it see this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types

Comment: This is [my error](https://i.imgur.com/WEE8Vy3.png) without `{mode: 'no-cors'}`. This is [my error](https://i.imgur.com/KCefZ8M.png) with `{mode: 'no-cors'}`. This is [my code](https://i.imgur.com/O1GkOQL.png). I added the `{mode: 'no-cors'}` for that same reason, what could i do?

@Samridh Tuladhar, where is that option?
@RajeshVerma, i let the SS there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by doing the following:

Thanks to **@Bravo**'s answer, I was able to get an idea of what my error was:

> "did you add that header due to a **CORS** error perhaps thinking this
> will bypass **CORS?**"

Since I am using `express.js` for my server, I had to install a middleware for my server, an npm module called **"cors"**.

So the only thing i needed to add was this line of code:

```
const cors = require('cors');

app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Anyway you can read more of this on [official documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) of cors in the official express.js website